# Playframework 2.4.x configuration file includes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

Playframework:2.4.4
Scala: 2.11
Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_66"

I'm trying to include configuration files in order to make environment specific configurations.

developer.conf:

```
include "application.conf"

db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mobile_server"
db.default.username="mobile_user"
db.default.password="password"

liquibase: {
    driver   = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    url      = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mobile_server"
    user     = "mobile_user"
    password = "password"
}
```

The issue is, it seems as if after going to the included "application.conf" file, the parser never returns to parse the rest of the 'main' file. So the database properties, for instance, are never set.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

So it seems my issue was forking during testing, to speed up testing times. When you do that it drops your "-D" options. In order to keep them you need to do something like this in your build.sbt file:

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=developer.conf"

which is described in the sbt documentation under "Forked JVM options":

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html

It essentially instructs sbt to pass the desired option along to all forked JVM processes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly tell activator to use your `developer.conf` file. Start activator like this:

```
activator -Dconfig.file=conf/developer.conf
```

What you are probably experiencing is not that it "only reads the include statement", but that activator just loads your default configuration file, which is `application.conf`, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: I'm doing -Dconfig.resource=developer.conf and I can tell it picks it up because if I pile everything into application.conf and run with -Dconfig.resource=developer.conf it will run just fine. So it does see the developer file and process the include it seems. 
The typo is me fat fingering in the post, it is right in the file. I'll fix the initial question, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you said proves that developer.conf is picked up. If you pile everything into application.conf, and it loads application.conf by default, it seems to me that it's obvious that it works. btw. You seem to use `-Dconfig.resource`, instead of `-Dconfig.file`.

Comment: A true proof would be to leave application.conf empty, put everything into developer.conf and then run it with `activator -Dconfig.file=conf/developer.conf`

Comment: Point taken about my assumption that it's picked up, I'll see if I can dis/prove that.
As far as the config setting, the play docs seem to say I can do either, though I did try the config.file with the same results.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration#Specifying-an-alternative-configuration-file

Comment: Maybe you can also just remove the `include` statement from your developer.conf file. If everything works then, you can be sure that it's not reading developer.conf.

Comment: tried putting everything into developer.conf then ... used config.resource(fail), config.file(fail), config.file w/"conf/developer.conf" since the doc says it needs the path from the root(fail).  I'm mistified.
Also tried removing the include an putting everything in application.conf, but specifying developer.conf... it ran fine, so it's just ignoring the -D settings.

Comment: Yes, you should use `conf/developer.conf`, and not just `developer.conf`. Please make sure that you're running activator from the root of your project, with exactly `activator -Dconfig.file=conf/developer.conf` and that your developer.conf file is indeed in the conf directory and that it's named correctly. I'm using this on ~10 projects and it's working fine.